# How to make a big image/dashboard containing various data-graph

Tags: graphics, image-processing, image, gui-construction

I want to make and image/dashborad (to export to PDF) with many VERTICAL bullet graphs gauges. And I can´t make it, in a automatic way.

In general, the questions are:

**QUESTION 1:** How to make a dashboard similar to this one:

[image]

For example, with only 3 gauges, I write this code:

```
GraphicsRow[
 Rotate[BulletGauge[{25, 98}, {80, 98, 107}, {0, 180}, 
   ImageSize -> Large], 90 Degree],
 Rotate[BulletGauge[{45, 62}, {20, 58, 107}, {0, 180}, 
   ImageSize -> Large], 90 Degree],
 Rotate[BulletGauge[{55, 82, 102}, {40, 88, 115}, {0, 180}, 
   ImageSize -> Large], 90 Degree]
 ]
```

and the result is:

[image]

I modified the code and put "{ }" to separate the 3 graphs, to obtain no commas between graphs, and the text "Graph..." and the brackets... but the result is so strange to me, because I can only view a little piece of the graphs.

**QUESTION 2:** Is this normal? How could I make my user view the entire graphs as in the previous image (without commas and "graph.." and brackets)?.

[image]

**QUESTION 3:** How I can rotate the text marks "0", "50", "150"... ?

Another way might be make automatic this individual bullet graphs, and find all I need in a PDF with LATEX, or in a similar way.

**What are the best options for achieving all these things?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For your purpose, you better use Row instead of GraphicsRow (Rotate[graphics..] is no longer graphics anyway). There is no option to set rotation of gauge tick but you could hack(?) to do that. I wrote a little function to rotate gauge and tick:

```
rotate[gauge_] := 
 Rotate[gauge /. Text[l_, r__] :> Text[Rotate[l, 270 Degree], r], 
  90 Degree]

rotate[BulletGauge[{25, 98}, {80, 98, 107}, {0, 180}, 
  ImageSize -> Large]]
```

[image]

Here's the result with Row:

```
color = {RGBColor[0.73`, 0.24506099999999992`, 0.1971`], 
   RGBColor[0.1971`, 0.5022473119339774`, 0.73`], 
   RGBColor[0.5356156238679548`, 0.73`, 0.1971`]};
Labeled[Row[
  rotate /@ {BulletGauge[{25, 98}, {80, 98, 107}, {0, 180}, 
     ImageSize -> Large], 
    BulletGauge[{45, 62}, {20, 58, 107}, {0, 180}, 
     ImageSize -> Large], 
    BulletGauge[{55, 82, 102}, {40, 88, 115}, {0, 180}, 
     ImageSize -> Large]}, Spacer[20]], 
 Row[{Style["Dashboard Example", "Subtitle", Darker[Red]], 
   SwatchLegend[color, 
    Thread[Style[{"Income", "Taxes", "blue"}, color]]]}, 
  Spacer[30]], Top]
```

[image]

Here's the code that scale gauge (but if you need very specific gauge, you might need to construct one by yourself and it could be easier than modifying built in one).

```
scaleRotate[g_, sc_: 1] := 
 rotate[Graphics[
   GeometricTransformation[g[[1]], ScalingTransform[{1, sc}]], 
   ImagePadding -> {{2, 2}, {15, 2}}, g[[2]]]]
```

Example:

```
color = {RGBColor[0.73`, 0.24506099999999992`, 0.1971`], 
   RGBColor[0.1971`, 0.5022473119339774`, 0.73`], 
   RGBColor[0.5356156238679548`, 0.73`, 0.1971`]};
Labeled[Row[
  scaleRotate[#, .25] & /@ 
   Table[BulletGauge[RandomInteger[{20, 100}, 3], 
     RandomInteger[{50, 120}, 3], {0, 180}, 
     ImageSize -> Large], {10}], Spacer[2]], 
 Row[{Style["Dashboard Example", "Subtitle", Darker[Red]], 
   SwatchLegend[color, 
    Thread[Style[{"Income", "Taxes", "blue"}, color]]]}, 
  Spacer[30]], Top]
```

[image]

Comment: perfect. Thank you. Only 2 more things. 1.- How could I obtain the thinner bullet graphs, for acomodate many many bars? (I tried with Scaled[] but have no good results)   AND 2.- What do you recommend me for learning Mathematica from a basic level?  Ane PDF, web, book?. I´m impressed for the knowledge of the people of the forum. In this case for you. Best Regards.

Comment: Here's the post that will help to learn Mathematica: [Where can I find examples of good Mathematica programming practice?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18/where-can-i-find-examples-of-good-mathematica-programming-practice)  I also add code to scaling.