# How to center Title/Label in a Bullet Gauge rotated? and how to add a second line?

Tags: gui-construction, labeling, rotation

My target is make a dashboard with VERTICAL bullet gauges (that is not available in Mathematica, only the horizontals), a [previous Q & A](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/40218) helped me to obtain vertical gauges (that its good but I would prefer *Mathematica* had the vertical option for customize easily.)

THE QUESTION is:

How to put The title/Label in each bullet gauge in the up/down position but CENTERED, as you can see in [image]

What I got is similar but not centered:
[image]

I would like to add a second line text in the Table, for example "MAN" and under this word "First",..... (similar to the first graph.)

So,
1.- How to center the TITLE/LABELS in each bullet graph
2.- How to add a second line in the TITLE/LABEL in each bullet graph

```
DataFile = {{"Man", "First", 215, 230, 120, 80, 65}, {"Man", "Second",
    240, 450, 180, 150, 114}, {"Woman", "First", 275, 450, 210, 190, 
   43}, {"Woman", "Second", 275, 275, 145, 134, 96}, {"Woman", 
   "Third", 200, 240, 20, 18, 12}}

NumeroPropiedades = Length[DataFile];
lonxitude = 
  Table[StringLength[DataFile[[i, 1]]], {i, 1, NumeroPropiedades}];
Max[lonxitude];

MaximoEscala = Max[Table[DataFile[[i, 4]], {i, 1, NumeroPropiedades}]];

rotate[gauge_] := 
 Rotate[gauge /. Text[l_, r__] :> Text[Rotate[l, 270 Degree], r], 
  90 Degree]
(* copied from http://ow.ly/zdSc302jZEm *)

BulletTOTAL = 
  Table[BulletGauge[{DataFile[[i, 5]], 
     DataFile[[i, 4]]*0.75}, {DataFile[[i, 3]]}, {0, DataFile[[i, 4]],
      DataFile[[i, 6]], DataFile[[i, 7]], MaximoEscala}, 
    ImageSize -> Large, 
    GaugeLabels -> 
     Placed[Style[Rotate[DataFile[[i, 1]], 3 Pi/2], "Subsection", 
       Black], Right]], {i, 1, NumeroPropiedades}];
Labeled[Row[rotate /@
   BulletTOTAL
  , Spacer[20]], 
 Row[{Style["Monthly", 39, "Subtitle", Darker[Red]]}, Spacer[30]], Top]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A modification of your last code block

```
BulletTOTAL = 
  Table[BulletGauge[{DataFile[[i, 5]], 
     DataFile[[i, 4]]*0.75}, {DataFile[[i, 3]]}, {0, DataFile[[i, 4]],
      DataFile[[i, 6]], DataFile[[i, 7]], MaximoEscala}, 
    ImageSize -> Large, 
    GaugeLabels -> 
     Placed[Style[
       Rotate[DataFile[[i, 2]] <> "\n" <> DataFile[[i, 1]], 3 Pi/2], 
       "Subsection", Black], {Right, Bottom}]], {i, 1, 
    NumeroPropiedades}];
Labeled[Row[rotate /@ BulletTOTAL, Spacer[20]], 
 Row[{Style["Monthly", 39, "Subtitle", Darker[Red]]}, 
  Spacer[30]], Top]
```

results in

[image: Out]

One can use `Column` to combine text with different `Style`s and `Center` to place the labels vertically centered to what *Mathematica* considers to be the center, instead of just placing them over the gauge as in the output shown above.

```
BulletTOTAL = 
  Table[BulletGauge[{DataFile[[i, 5]], 
     DataFile[[i, 4]]*0.75}, {DataFile[[i, 3]]}, {0, DataFile[[i, 4]],
      DataFile[[i, 6]], DataFile[[i, 7]], MaximoEscala}, 
    ImageSize -> Large, 
    GaugeLabels -> 
     Placed[Framed@
       Rotate[Column[{Style[DataFile[[i, 2]], 25], 
          Style[DataFile[[i, 1]], 38, Bold], "|"}, Center], 
        3 Pi/2], {Right, Center}]], {i, 1, NumeroPropiedades}];
Labeled[Row[rotate /@ BulletTOTAL, Spacer[20]], 
 Row[{Style["Monthly", 39, "Subtitle", Darker[Red]]}, 
  Spacer[30]], Top]
```

[image: Out2]

One can see from this plot that the placement is relative to the axis of the gauge. To center the text relative to the gauge itself:

```
BulletTOTAL = 
  Table[BulletGauge[{DataFile[[i, 5]], 
     DataFile[[i, 4]]*0.75}, {DataFile[[i, 3]]}, {0, DataFile[[i, 4]],
      DataFile[[i, 6]], DataFile[[i, 7]], MaximoEscala}, 
    ImageSize -> Large, 
    GaugeLabels -> 
     Placed[Framed@
       Rotate[Column[{Style[DataFile[[i, 2]], 18], 
          Style[DataFile[[i, 1]], 25, Bold]}, Center], 3 Pi/2], {1, 2/3}]], 
   {i, 1, NumeroPropiedades}];
Labeled[Row[rotate /@ BulletTOTAL, Spacer[20]], 
 Row[{Style["Monthly", 39, "Subtitle", Darker[Red]]}, 
  Spacer[30]], Top]
```

[image: Out3]

Comment: Thank you, I like it, but a little thing. The first bullet has the Titles centered, but the next ones no. In the case of WOMAN they semms to be not centered. Moreover, the space between bullet gauges seems to depend on the text of TITLE/LABEL. of bullet gauges

Comment: @MikaIke See my edit. The first ones are also not centered. Their right boarders are aligned with the axis of the gauge. The second ones now show that the placement is relative to the axis of the gauge. For the last ones the text should be centered to the gauge itself.

Comment: Thank you very much. ok. I see. The edit yout edit. Perfect :-)

Comment: If you don´t rotate the bullet graphics, all works fine, and you obtain a PDF with the titles and all the numbers. I think that Wolfram must consider a funtion to do VERTICAL Bullets.

Comment: @MikaIke Is `VerticalGauge[9, {0, 10}, 
 GaugeLabels -> Placed[Style["Above", "Subsection"], Above]]` exportable to PDF without any issues? If that's the case, I can recreate the `BulletGauge` based on `VerticalGauge`.

Comment: Yes, I have create 2 copies in a Row and export to PDF all ok. But I like very much all de options of the BuletGauge. Don´t make the effort karsten-7. In the next weeks I will use BulletGauges that you help me in horizontal, and then turn it into a LaTeX document. This would be not a problem if Mathematica would have the option of vertical gauges. I can´t understand the reason of only horizontal is available.