# How to create a vertical bullet gauge?

Tags: graphics, data, visualization

*Originally posted in MathematicaMeta SE, titled "I can't understand why Mathematica has an excellent (perhaps the best!) BulletGauge command (with multiple options)", as a reflexion about the inconsistence of Mathematica has the best (comparing with other software) Bulletguage command BUT ONLY in HORIZONTAL!! without an option to make it VERTICAL nativelly*

I can't understand why *Mathematica* has an excellent (perhaps the best!) [`BulletGauge`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BulletGauge.html) command (with multiple options)

[image]

BUT.... 
only in horizontal!!!

AND 
it´s not available in Vertical!!

There is an SE-Solution (Stack Exchange Solution):

- [How to make a big image/dashboard containing various data-graph](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/40218/how-to-make-a-big-image-dashboard-containing-various-data-graph)

but

It's really a pity and I can't understand why is not available an option to do it in vertical.

Best regards.
I don't know if this site is for this kind of opinions.

Comment: If you rephrase it too e.g. "how to create a vertical gauge? I was only able to find a horizontal one" then it will fit here well.

Comment: I changed the question title as per Kuba's suggestion so that the question will be easier to find in the future, e.g. when searching on Google.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### "GaugeOrigin"

**Update:** it turns out that there is an undocumented option `"GaugeOrigin"` that controls the orientation of the gauge.

```
BulletGauge[{42, 82}, {40, 68, 97}, {0, 100}, "GaugeOrigin" -> #, ImageSize ->Medium] & /@
   {Bottom, Top, Left, Right} // Row[#, Spacer[10]] &
```

[image]

In version 9, this produces the error message

> OptionValue::nodef: Unknown option "GaugeOrigin" for BulletGauge

but gives the correct result. So you can suppress the error message using `Quiet` or use it a suboption of the option `Method`, i.e., `Method -> {"GaugeOrigin" -> Bottom}` works without complaint.

**Update 2:**  The option `"TickLength"` controls the tick lengths:

```
BulletGauge[{42, 82}, {40, 68, 97}, {0, 100}, 
   "GaugeOrigin" -> #, "TickLength" -> Scaled[.3], ImageSize -> Medium] & /@
 {Bottom,  Top, Left, Right} // Row[#, Spacer[10]] &
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

You can post-process a `BulletGauge` to make it vertical:

```
bg = BulletGauge[{42, 82}, {40, 68, 97}, {0, 100}]
```

[image]

```
makeVertical = Graphics[GeometricTransformation[#[[1]], RotationTransform[Pi/2]] /.
  Text[a___, Offset[o_, p_], off_, dir_] :> 
   Text[a, Offset[{0, -20}, p], {1, 0}, -Reverse @ dir]] &;

makeVertical @ bg
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much. One question and one reflexion. The question How to control the sixe of segments between graph and Numbers?. https://imgur.com/a/G4Wji  The reflexion: People with your Mathemtica knowledge or similar can do that kind of things, but I couln´t do it. So I can´t understand why Mathematica can´t offer that feature in a simple way. The purpose of a software should be make easier assignments/works and not offer a close-up solution that need a sophisticated procedure to can apply it.

Comment: If I can make a HORIZONTAL bullet gauge in a minute. Logically, I would can make a VERTICAL bullet gauge in the same time, if the software it´s designed with a minimal logic. Without your help or other, I need months to reach the solution to make a VERTICAL bullet gauge, when I can do an HORIZONTAL bullet in less than 1 minute. It´s that what I can´t underestand in the design of Mathematica.

Comment: @MikaIke, Thank you for the accept. I too am surprised that such a natural feature is not available out of the box. I will post an update with the parameters that control the tick lengths.

Comment: THANK YOU. INCREDIBLE!!! answer :-) undocumented option!!! "GaugeOrigin" ->Bottom EXCELENT!!  Now I can´t understand why this is an undocumented option! :-) but you have solve many of my question. This is a graph that I like very much. It concentrate so many info!

Comment: I can´t believe what you have written!! :-) but It´s really true!!!, IT works fine!!! excelent!!! but... I can´t view that option when I execute Options[BulletGauge] in Win 8 + Mathematica 11  :-) https://imgur.com/a/XyS9b  You´re a hackker!! :-) a fantastic hacker! ;-) thank you, once more.

Comment: @MikaIke, the option `"GaugeOrigin"`  appears in ``Options[Charting`iLinearGauge]``  where ``Charting`iLinearGauge`` is one of the functions called by `BulletGauge`.

Comment: THANK YOU!Excuse for trying to understand how you achieve that info. 3 Questions: Q1.- How have you known that BulletGauge calls Charting`iLinearGauge (I have never viewed the apostroph ` in Functions and I can´t view it in Options https://imgur.com/a/XyS9b ). I can´t see it in Options[GaugeBullet] I cna´t see neitherCharting nor iLinearGaue *Q2.- How have you known that Bottom, Top, Left, Right are the options for the GaugeOrigin. *Q3.- Why GaugeOrigin apears in red (as using semicolon " " as using nothing) although working fine?  https://imgur.com/a/DOAk1 in the opposite of ImageSize .

Comment: @MikaIke, re (Q1) for some functions you can see the code using ``Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]`` followed by `PrintDefinitions[BulletGauge]`. There you see the call to ``Charting`iLinearGauge``.   (Q2) Based on `BarOrigin` for  `Histogram/BarChart` it was a lucky guess that Left/Right/Top/Bottom might work:) (Q3) Red highlight indicates syntax error which i guess is related to the fact that this usage pattern is undocumented and syntax highlighting subsystem treats it as error.

Answer (score 0):

I think using `Rotate` is pretty "out of the box" solution (although the tick labels are not rotated.)

```
bg = BulletGauge[{42, 82}, {40, 68, 97}, {0, 100}];
Rotate[bg, Pi/2]
```

[image]

Comment: for rotate the text you have solutions at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/40218/how-to-make-a-big-image-dashboard-containing-various-data-graph but kglr gave us THE SOLUTION !! . He gave us the solution that Mathematica and Wolfram doesn´t show us.

Comment: @MikaIke Well, adding the code of [the label rotation answer your referenced](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/40221/34008) would make this solution less "out of the box".